# Finding basis and dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey can some help me with this textbook question

Let $R^{2×2}$ denote the vector space of 2×2 matrices, and let

$S =\left\{
\left[\begin{matrix}
a \space b \\ 
b \space c \\
\end{matrix}\right]\mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Find (with justication) a basis for $S$ and determine the dimension of $S$.

Comment: Hint: Think of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ as a funny way of writing $[\begin{smallmatrix} a&b&c&d\end{smallmatrix}]$.  $S$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ where the second coordinate equals the third one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ is a four-dimensional space, so the dimension of $S$ is at most $4$. In fact, it's at most $3$ since the set $S$ does not contain the matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$

So $S$ in fact has dimension at most $3$.

---

Can you find three linearly independent vectors in $S$? Note that you have three variables: $a$, $b$, and $c$; this should guide your construction.

---

As discussed in the comments below, three such matrices are

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right], \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right], \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I understand the dimension part but could u explain to be what basis is?

Comment: @mathisawesome A basis is a linearly independent spanning set. So if you can find three linearly independent vectors in $S$, they have to span $S$; do you see why?

Comment: why do they have to be 3 vectors why isnt the basis a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: @mathisawesome The word "vector" in this context refers to an element of the set $S$ - so a "vector" is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: So i have to find 3 2x2 vector that are in S?

Comment: @mathisawesome Yes, you need to find three $2 \times 2$ *matrices* which are elements of $S$ with the additional condition that they are linearly independent as elements of $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$.

Comment: So would $\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{array}\right]$ be an acceptable answer since they are 3 matrices that are linearly independent?

Comment: @mathisawesome They aren't independent; they are all multiples of each other.

Comment: What about $\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$

Comment: @mathisawesome The second two matrices are good, but the first isn't in $S$.

Comment: what if it is $\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$

Comment: @mathisawesome Yes. Combined with the other two matrices, that does it.

Comment: But i got this by using different matrices that satifies the requirment is that alright or is there a specific way of finding the 3 matrices

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$S = \{\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\b&c\end{array}\right]: a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
$$ = \{\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}
{cc}0&b\\b&0\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&c\end{array}\right]: a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
$$ = \{a\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]+b\left[\begin{array}
{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]+c\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]: a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
$$ = \operatorname{span}\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]\right).$$

Moreover, the list $\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]\right)$ is linearly independent (why?). Hence it is a basis for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

$S =\left\{
\left[\begin{matrix}
a \space b \\ 
b \space c \\
\end{matrix}\right]\mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

or [a  b  b  c]---------------(1)

Put values {[1  0  0  0 ],[0  1  0  0],[0  0  1  0],[0  0  0  1]} in (1)
we get

{[1  0  0  0 ],[0  1  1  0],[0  1  1  0],[0  0  0  1]}

$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \space 0 \space 0  \space 0 \\ 
0 \space1 \space 1  \space 0 \\
0 \space1 \space 1  \space 0 \\
0 \space 0 \space 0  \space 1 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]$

I will reduce to

$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \space 0 \space 0  \space 0 \\ 
0 \space1 \space 1  \space 0 \\
0 \space0 \space0  \space 0 \\
0 \space 0 \space 0  \space 1 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right]$

its rank is 3,So dimension of basis of S is 3

Basis ={[1  0  0  0 ],[0  1  1  0],[0  0  0  1]} (see the reduced matrix)

Basis ={
$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \space 0  \\ 
0 \space0  \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$,$
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \space 1  \\ 
1 \space0  \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$,$
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \space 0  \\ 
0 \space1  \\
 \end{matrix}\right]$}